# How do I reference simple vectors from one code chunk to another in knitr?

Tags: r, vector, knitr

I'm new to R, and trying to work a side project to supplement my in-class learning.

How on earth do I reference simple vectors from one code chunk to another in knitr?

For example, if I have a user input 3 values, and want to use those values in a later chunk, what's the best way to do so?
EX:

````
```{R User Input, echo=FALSE, REPLACE=FALSE}
redoffensedicenumber <-   as.numeric(readline(prompt="Red Dice : "))
blackoffensedicenumber <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Black Dice : "))
whiteoffensedicenumber <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="White Dice : "))
```

```{R Create Storage Matrix, eval=FALSE, include=FALSE}
zero <- c(0)
storagematrix <- matrix (zero, nrow = 10000 , ncol = redoffensedicenumber + blackoffensedicenumber + whiteoffensedicenumber , byrow = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: With `knitr` as long as you are using `r` for your engine, you should be able to use variables in later chunks. What problem are you running into with your code?

Comment: I figured out a workaround.  If I output the variables, knitr can reference them later